# How to understand the parameter reduction set to ‘none’ in the F.cross_entropy function in pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, torch

I would like to use heat maps for pixel classification tasks. Currently, I have a classification heat map with predicted results, with dimensions (batch_num, C, H, W), as well as a ground truth heat map with dimensions (batch_num, C, H, W). At the same time, I want each pixel to have different levels of attention in different channels, so I have generated an energy matrix with dimensions (batch_num, C, H, W). In my experiment, I expect to put this energy matrix into `F.cross_entropy(classification, class_heat_maps, reduction='none')` to get a result with dimensions (batch_num, C, H, W), which I will use for element-wise multiplication with my energy matrix.

This is my code:

```
classification_loss=total_class_energy*F.cross_entropy(classification,class_heat_maps,reduction='none')
classification_loss=torch.sum(classification_loss,dim=1)
classification_loss=torch.mean(classification_loss)
```

Could you explain why the dimensions generated by my `F.cross_entropy(classification, class_heat_maps, reduction='none')` function in the experiment are (batch_num, H, W)? 
Do I need to customize a cross entropy function to achieve my goal?

Comment: Because C is the number of classes, if you read the document carefully, it's written that: inputs `(N, C, d1, ...)` -> output `(N, d1, ...)`.